# Dynamically Nested Tab Creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I am trying to achieve dynamically nested tab based on my data set.I am able to achieve parent tab successfully but having a issue with child tab.
Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var data1 = [["FINANCE"],["SALE"],["SALE3"]];
var data2=[["FINANCE","FINANCE1"],["FINANCE","FINANCE2"],["SALE","SALE1"],["SALE","SALE2"],["SALE","SALE3"],["SALE","SALE4"],["SALE3","NOSALE"]]
 var stringData = "";
var dyn_div="";
var dyn_ul="";
var dyn_li='';
for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
  stringData = "<li><a data-toggle='tab'  href=#"+data1[i]+">"+data1[i]+"</a></li>"
  $(".list").append(stringData);
  $(".list li:first-child").addClass("active");
  dyn_div="<div class='tab-pane fade' id="+data1[i]+">'<ul class='p nav nav-tabs'>";
for(var j=i;j< data2.length;j++)
{    
      if(data2[j][0]==data1[i]){

        dyn_li= "<li><a data-toggle='tab'  href=#"+data2[j][1]+">"+data2[j][1]+"</a></li>" 
         $(".p").append(dyn_li);
       dyn_div +='</ul></div>';
          $(".tab-content").append(dyn_div);
          }
          else
          {
          dyn_li=''
           $(".p").append('');
          }

             } 
 }
 $(".p li:first-child").addClass("active");
 $(".tab-content div.tab-pane:first-child").addClass("active in");
 })
```

HTML Code

```
<ul class="list nav nav-tabs"></ul>
<div class="tab-content"></div>
```

OUTPUT
[image]

I am unable to understand where i am doing .The FINANCE Tab have only FINANCE child like Finance1 ,Finance and SALE Tab have only SALE child tab.Can anyone help me to identified the issue where i am doing wrong.

Comment: a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would really help us better appreciate the problem. while an image may represent a thousand words, a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) represents a thousand images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to format your code for easy to read

You used wrong param to compare `data1[i]` instead of `data1[i][0]`. That make wrong href also

You need to append all in data to `dyn_div`. Don't use `$(.p).append`, that will get the appended item instead of current item.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data1 = [
        ["FINANCE"],
        ["SALE"],
        ["SALE3"]
    ];
    var data2 = [
        ["FINANCE", "FINANCE1"],
        ["FINANCE", "FINANCE2"],
        ["SALE", "SALE1"],
        ["SALE", "SALE2"],
        ["SALE", "SALE3"],
        ["SALE", "SALE4"],
        ["SALE3", "NOSALE"]
    ]
    var stringData = "";
    var dyn_ul = "";
    var dyn_li = '';
    var dyn_div = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
        stringData = $("<li><a data-toggle='tab'  href=#" + data1[i][0] + ">" + data1[i][0] + "</a></li>");
        $(".list").append(stringData);
        $(".list li:first-child").addClass("active");
        dyn_div = "<div class='tab-pane fade' id=" + data1[i][0] + "><ul class='p nav nav-tabs'>";
        for (var j = 0; j < data2.length; j++) {
            if (data2[j][0] === data1[i][0]) {
                dyn_div += "<li><a data-toggle='tab'  href=#" + data2[j][1] + ">" + data2[j][1] + "</a></li>";
            }
        }
        dyn_div += '</ul></div>';
        $(".tab-content").append(dyn_div);
    }
    $(".p li:first-child").addClass("active");
    $(".tab-content div.tab-pane:first-child").addClass("active in");
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response..Thats work very fine

Answer (score 0):

Although this might not be a 100% working solution I believe your main error here is the line `$(".p").append(dyn_li);`
Since at some point there are more than one element with class `p` this will double everything.

So here is my rough untested suggestion:

```
    var data1 = [["FINANCE"],["SALE"],["SALE3"]];
    var data2=[["FINANCE","FINANCE1"],["FINANCE","FINANCE2"],["SALE","SALE1"],["SALE","SALE2"],["SALE","SALE3"],["SALE","SALE4"],["SALE3","NOSALE"]]
    var stringData = "";
    var dyn_div="";
    var dyn_ul="";
    var dyn_li='';
    for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {

        stringData = "<li><a data-toggle='tab' href=#"+data1[i]+">"+data1[i]+"</a></li>"
        $(".list").append(stringData); // this element should also be addressed by an unique ID, but if there is only one element with that class, it's fine
        dyn_div="<div class='tab-pane fade' id="+data1[i]+">'<ul class='p nav nav-tabs'>";
        for(var j=i;j< data2.length;j++){    
          if(data2[j][0]==data1[i]){
                dyn_li= "<li><a data-toggle='tab'  href=#"+data2[j][1]+">"+data2[j][1]+"</a></li>" 
                $("#"+data1[i]).find('.p').first().append(dyn_li); // Here big change
                dyn_div +='</ul></div>';
                $(".tab-content").append(dyn_div); // this also needs to be a unique DOM element
            }
        } 
     }
     $(".p li:first-child").addClass("active");
     $(".tab-content div.tab-pane:first-child").addClass("active in");
```